# Showing warning when IE 9 compatibility mode detected

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, ie-developer-tools

I would like to detect compatibility mode in IE9 and show user the warning message.

My compatibility view settings are "Display all website in compatibility mode". But, still this condition is not true for IE9.

```
if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE 7.0") > 0 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Trident/5.0") > 0).
```

I can verify from F12 option that I am in IE 9 compatibility mode. When I printed navigator.userAgent, it shows MSIE 9.0.

But, from F12 option, if I change from compatbility mode to normal mode and then compatilibity mode, I can see userAget has MSIE 7.0 and condition becomes true.

How can it be resolved ?

Is there any website on internet which shows such warning if we open it in IE9 compatibility mode ?

Comment: The best answer I can give is to stop using compatibility mode. There's no good reason to use it -- why cripple your browser deliberately by removing features? And compat mode isn't even very good at being fully backward compatible anyway. Just use the `X-UA-Compatible` meta tag to force IE to use standards mode, and leave it at that. (btw; when you upgrade to IE11, you'll find that the option to switch to compat mode from the dev tools has been removed because MS want to discourage its use).

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of tests for XPath APIs, user-agent substrings, and window properties to identify IE9 compatibility mode:

```
//IE XPath API
if (!!window.XPathEvaluator === false && !!window.XPathExpression === false)
  {
  //Compatibility Mode
  if(/compatible/.test(navigator.userAgent) )
    {
    //IE9 innerWidth property exists, but IE10 matchMedia property does not
    if(!!window.innerWidth && !window.matchMedia)
      {
      alert("IE9 compatibility mode");
      }
    }
  }
```